# can jquery do width: 'hide' without making element display:none ?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate an element without jquery making it display:none
is there anyway to do it ???

and also when I just have the sibliings() opacity:0
the ul opacity wouldn't go back to 1 ? 
is it because widht:'show' can't be used along with opacity ?

thanks heaps !

jquery:

```
$("#nav li ").click(function(){ 

    $(this).find(">ul").dequeue().animate({width:'show',opacity:1},300);
    $(this).siblings().find(">ul").dequeue().animate({width:'hide',opacity:0},300);

});
```

2nd version ul opacity wouldn't go back to 1:

```
$("#nav li ").click(function(){ 

    $(this).find(">ul").dequeue().animate({width:'show',opacity:1},300);
    $(this).siblings().find(">ul").dequeue().animate({opacity:0},300);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using hide, show or toggle will change the display properties, try using width '0' and then animate back to the original width again instead.

Answer (score 0):

In think you want to send an actual width value to "width":

```
$("#nav li ").click(function(){ 

    $(this).find(">ul").dequeue().animate({opacity:1},300);
    $(this).siblings().find(">ul").dequeue().animate({width:'0px',opacity:0},300);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

.animate({width: "0", overflow: "hidden"});

i think you'll need the overflow styling to ensure that the contents are actually hidden.